# unassigned value in the int[ ]

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Would like to know in C++ what the value of unassigned integer in an `int[]` usually is.

Example

```
int arr[5];
arr[1]=2;
arr[3]=4;
for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
{
  cout <<arr[i] <<endl;
}
```

it print

```
-858993460
2
-858993460
4
-858993460
```

we know that the array will be `{?,2,?,4,?}` ,where ? is unknown.

What will the "?" be usually?

When I tested , I always got negative value. 
Can I assume in C++ unassigned element in the integer array is always less than or equal to zero?

Correct me if I'm wrong. When I study in Java unassigned element in array will produce null.

Comment: You cannot assume anything - it's undefined behavior and you shouldn't rely on it.

Comment: is there anyway to make int arr[5] = {}; producing sets of -1 or other value rather than just zero?

Comment: `int arr[5]; std::fill(arr, arr + 5, -1);`

Comment: @YuvinNg, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17828567/unassigned-value-in-the-int/17828581?noredirect=1#comment26020547_17828594. Alternatively, use something like `std::vector` and pass it into the constructor.

Comment: There is no default initialization in c/c++. Per definition all unassigned values are undefined, i.e. may contain random values. Often they are assigned with special values to mark it as "unassigned" like 0xcccccccc (in your case).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Formally, in most cases the very attempt to read an uninitialized value results in undefined behavior. So, formally the question about the actual value is rather moot: you are not allowed to even look at that value directly.

Practically, uninitialized values in C and C++ are unpredictable. On top of that they are not supposed to be stable, meaning that reading the same uninitialized value several times is not guaranteed to read the same value.

If you need a pre-initialized local array, declare it with an explicit initializer

```
int arr[5] = {};
```

The above is guaranteed to fill the array with integer zeros.

Comment: That's very interesting, especially regarding the instability part: can you provide some documentation about that?

Comment: all right, 
because right now im trying to create an int array let say of the size 100 and randomly insert postive integer into any position in the array. 
If the array is not full. how could i determine if that position in the array has never been assigned.

Comment: @AndreyT Why [`int array[] = {};`](http://codepad.org/Q3RNPv32) is valid code **?** I do not understand it?

Comment: @YuvinNg you cannot determine that, unless you keep track of it yourself.

Comment: @Yuvin Ng: You can't. That is unless you have a "reserved" value that can be used to mark "unused" elements. (For example, if you know tha you will never encounter `INT_MIN` in your application, you can use `INT_MIN` to fill the array initially.) Otherwise, you have to implement it by other means.

Comment: @YuvinNg, You might just want a `std::map`.

Comment: @Grijesh Chauhan: `int array[] = {};` is not valid code. `int array[5] = {};` is. When you use `{}` initilizer, the array size has to be specified explicitly.

Comment: @AndreyT I given a link at code http://codepad.org/Q3RNPv32 surprisingly its working

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan, That's a GCC extension.

Comment: @AndreyT all right i tested int arr[5] = {}; and it make those garbage value into 0. that great,
i would like to know if its possible to assign other value other than zero? let say -1 to represent it is "empty position".Thanks

Comment: @YuvinNg, `std::fill`.

Comment: Anyway, the most general way for not yet used elements, without using a map or something, would be `boost::optional`, soon to be standard.

Comment: @Antonio: There no documentation for the behavior that is simply undefined. The explanation for the potential reasons for the instability can be found here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17394907/c-is-an-indeterminate-value-indeterminable

Comment: @Grijesh Chauhan: It means that the compiler running under codepad has very loose error checking. It probably interprets it as an array of size zero. Such arrays are explicitly illegal in C and C++, but that compiler apparently accepts them as a non-standard extension.

Comment: @YuvinNg: "randomly insert postive integer into any position in the array" - a better approach is to fill the array from `[0]` through `[99]` - easier to keep track of which elements you've populated - then use the Standard library to shuffle the array elements into random positions - see http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle

Comment: @TonyD, But you should still initialize every element within that index range, right? I would think it needs the ones it's swapping to be.

Comment: @chris: that's exactly right - you initialise all elements then let the shuffle take care of randomising it, instead of randomly selecting positions as you insert, then wondering which ones you haven't populated yet....

Comment: @TonyD, Agreed, but I still think a `std::map` makes it much easier. Add them where you want when you want and it's easy to iterate over the ones there :)

Comment: @chris: most times people ask for something like this, they want to prepopulate all elements so they can start doing random lookups... if that's not the case, they could populate however many they want, sort them, then as new ones arrive pick a random index up to the new size, swapping the current element value to the end if necessary. Using a map for ordered iteration over randomly positioned elements seems unlikely to be useful, but ultimately it depends what Yuvin Ng wants to do, and whether he has the experience to recognise the best suggestion (which could still be `map`).

Comment: @TonyD, True, and there's `std::unordered_map` as well, seeing as how the ordering probably isn't important.

Comment: @chris: oops... I mean "..however many they want, SHUFFLE them, then as new...".  Separately, if the intent of a `map` or `unordered_map` is to both serve as a free list (i.e. allow quick identification of an unpopulated element = quick insertion), and find a random populated element, what should the keys and values be?  Could you even do these two operations - both in better than O(N) time - with either container alone?

Comment: @bkausbk: That will initialize `a[0]` with `-12345678` and the rest with zeros. That is not what the OP meant by initializing with "arbitrary values".

Comment: @AndreyT Ok problem solved, this also compilers with my `gcc`,  but if I use ` -pendatic -error` it gives error that array size `0` or -ve.

Comment: @bkausbk: Well, yes, it will "initialize the entire array". As I said above, `a[0]` will be initialized with `-12345678`, while the rest will be initialized with zeros. And no, it will not set all elements to `-12345678`, if that's what you mean. You can "test" it if you want.

Answer (score 1):

> When I tested , I always got negative value.

The (previously) unused memory space seemed filled with the hex code 0xCC. However, as mentioned above -- several times -- you cannot *rely* on this.

In one of your comments you clarify your task:

> im trying to create an int array let say of the size 100 and randomly insert postive integer into any position in the array. If the array is not full. how could i determine if that position in the array has never been assigned[?]

Fill the array with zeros (manually, or per AndrewT's answer). Since you are inserting positive integers only, all you have to test for is !0.

Answer (score 0):

The values contained in an unitialized area of memory can be anything, it is implementation depending. The most efficient implementation is to leave the memory as it was, so you will find in your array whatever was contained before. An important note: [it is not something you can use as a random value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1450862/2436175). Some implementation (I have seen that, especially in the past, when compiling and running in debug mode) might put zeros in your memory, but it is uncommon. You simply should not rely on the content of uninitialized area of memory.

To understand if something has not been touched in your array, you can initialize it to some value like DEADBEEF:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexspeak

(Unless you are so unlucky that one of the values you have to insert corresponds exactly to DEADBEEF... :) )

Comment: Most "debug" implementations won't default initialize to zero because that *hides* errors. They want to use something that will highlight them, like `0xDEADBEEF` in your example, or `0xCCCCCCCC` in MSVC's runtime library.

Comment: @CodyGray I am referring to some behaviour I experienced in the past, and I do agree that it was misleading.

Comment: @CodyGray: -858993460 should be 0xCCCCCCCC in his example not 0xDEADBEEF.

Comment: @bkausbk What? I don't understand what you're saying. Whose example? Antonio is just giving random examples of magic numbers.

Comment: @CodyGray: I was talking about the original authors question where uninitialized values contains -858993460 which is 0xCCCCCCCC.

Answer (score 0):

You can't know what this will produce, since it takes as value the bits that are in memory in that moment. So you can get ANY value, not only negative values.

Comment: Actually your computer can explode; you can also not get *any* value; the behaviour is *undefined*.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz Are you sure the behaviour is undefined, or rather that it is undefined the value that you will read?

Comment: Formally, the mere attempt to read an uninitialized value is undefined. In practice, it just returns an undefined value.

Answer (score 0):

These are garbage values, you cannot expect to work with these variables properly and they will not predict what it may result into. Whenever a variable gets allocated some portion of memory gets allocated for that variable and those portion may be used previously for some other unknown calculation which you cannot know, so you have to intialize those variables with some values to avoid usage of garbage values.

Answer (score 0):

You are not assigning any value at these locations. So it will return garbage values from memory. You must put some values at these locations. Unimplemented locations will returned in some unexpected/unpredictable values.